How do I solve an APS authentication error?
This is the error message: Server listening on port xxxx...
Error status: 403
Error data: {
developerMessage: 'The client_id specified does not have access to the api product',
moreInfo: 'https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/',
errorCode: 'AUTH-001'
}
Error headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Thu, 11 Jul 2024 07:42:33 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '204',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
'x-request-id': '78878a7b-a69f-4c68-9811-721e97d73998'
}
I'm trying to use and customize APS Viewer

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
